# How could I make this PHP $_POST more secure? -Or is it secure already?

Tags: php, mysql, security, post

On most my $_post data inputted on my site I use the following php:

```
$example = $_POST['textfield'];
$example = strip_tags($example);
$example = mysql_real_escape_string($example);
```

And then I would interact with the MySQL database...

Is this 'secure' / 'safe'?

Any major exploits to the above code?

-How could I make it secure?

Comment: [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: There is no reason for striptags at this point.

Comment: I think it looks good.  You've stopped cross site attacks with strip tags and youve made it safe for sql.

Comment: And i disagree with codeinchaos,  strip tags is needed if you plan on displaying this or make sure you run special chars on it when you output it.

Comment: As in html_specialchars?

Comment: Yes.  I you dint want to run strip tags.

Comment: @espradley It's generally best to do `strip_tags` type stuff on output, not input, in case you wind up unexpectedly needing those tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One last thing to do is to validate the data:

you can check if its an empty string? a number? or whatever data type you are expecting. example if you are expecting an email, you can use regex to confirm that it is an actual email.

Comment: But that's not a security issue is it? I.E in a search?

Comment: The body of the question asks if this is 'secure'/'safe' - and data validation definitely falls in the bounds of making things safer.

Comment: @James, if you don't validate your data after cleansing it, you may as well have not bothered cleansing it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_real_escape_string makes it quite safe

it always depends on what you want to do with the values.
eg. you dont wan't to strip_tags a password, you should just MD5 it.
If your storing it to be displayed on another page, you should use html_specialchars to dissable -hacking

and sometimen you should validate is an input is an integer, if it doesn't conatin numbers, if the is no A in it,...

so it realy depends

Comment: Whats difference in html_specialchars and strip_tags?

Comment: stipttags: "<p>hey hey</p>"  ----->>>>  "hey hey" .. the diference with htmlespecialchars is taht the tags stay but there encoded to be unxcutable:  
htmlspecialchars:  "<p>hey hey</p>"  ---->>>> "&lt;p&gt;hey hey "&lt;/p&gt;

Comment: if a user wants to type <p> it won't be deleted

Comment: but if I want to disallow all html across my site, strip_tags is good enough to stop it?

Comment: yes, of cource, but htmlspecialchars wil stop them ass wel but the tags will be readable (but not for the browsers, in other words fake tags)

Answer (score 1):

While `mysql_real_escape_string()` protects against SQL-injection, still unwanted behavior might exist.

**Note, that `mysql_real_escape_string()` does not escape `%` or `_`.**

Thus, if a user enters e.g. `%` in a posted form field, a `LIKE` where clause may return much more data than intended.

See final hint in PHP manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).